# How to convert text into variable name to print its value using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, innerhtml

I have a function that writes a text into html document. This text is equal to the values of two variables, and the result is equal to the name of a third variable. How can I convert this final text into a variable name to make the function print it's value?

```html
<script>
function start()
{
var name1 = "name";
var name2 = 3;
var name3 = "Text that I want to write";

document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = name1 + name2;


}
</script>

<div id="here"></div>

<button onclick="start()">
Start
</button>
```

UPD: There was a tupo `var name1 = "test"`, it should be `var test1 = "name"`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'm confused

Comment: You'll need to clarify your requirements. It's entirely unclear what you hope to achieve here. There's seems to be nothing expressly wrong with your code so far, except for changing name1 + name2 to name3 perhaps? Or are you trying to get the content of another item called text3 that isn't shown here? *confused*

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "This text is equal to the values of two variables, and the result is equal to the name of a third variable." What is "the result". If you just want to have the addition of the two strings name1 and name2 into a variable then simply assign it to a variable before you set the innerHtml value. E.g. var value1 = name1 + name2;

Comment: I'm very sorry that I confused you, the answer below solves my problem, maybe it will help you to understand what I mean.

Comment: There was a tupo : var name1 = "test". It should be var test1 = "name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)!

```
<script>
function start() {
  var names = {
    name1: "name",
    name2: "3",
    name3: "Text that I want to write"
  }

  document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = names[names.name1 + names.name2];
}
</script>

<div id="here"></div>
<button onclick="start()">start</button>
```

Comment: What? This doesn't make sense

Comment: It WORKS!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: This makes total sense, assuming `var name1 = "text";` is a typo for `var name1 = "name";`  – which seems to be the case based on the question.

Comment: @RickHitchcock yes, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you meant for name1 to equal "name" instead of "text." Then by putting it together, you will get the third variable which holds the value of text you want to print. In this case, you can use the `eval()` function of javascript.

Instead of

```
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = name1 + name2;
```

use

```
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = eval(name1 + name2);
```

Comment: Thank you, there was a typo. This method doesn't work in my case, maybe I wrote something wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/MaximVelichkin/c0s9bkLa/5/

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: Nothing, I added a link to the previous comment

Comment: Ah, thats because you changed the declarations from independent lines. If you maintained the structure in the question, it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/c0s9bkLa/6/

Comment: Now I see, thank you very much!